# ruby pattern for file data collection and individual records

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns

I'm looking for a suitable pattern for an application that uses various data files.  The basic process will be, run the script, load the data file(s), do stuff, output a report or new data file (no alteration of input files).

The files are various formats but for arguments sake, say they are CSV - the format is not a factor here.

I am attracted to the ActiveRecord style pattern where you have a class representing a dataset.  There are class methods through which you can retrieve data, and each record is an instance, with instance methods for each field.

In my case that would look something like

```
class People
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :addresss, :city, :country
  def self.load(file)
    rtn = self.new
    @cache = []
    # load data into @cache instance var, each row of data is an instance of self
    rtn
  end
  def all_people
    @cache
  end
  def people_in_city(city)
    # search @cache for matching records
  end
  def people_with_last_name(name)
    # search @cache for matching records
  end
  # etc, etc
end
```

This kind of works but it feels clunky.  Each instance not only has an individual record data, but also a reference to all the data in the file (i.e. `@cache`).  So this is a big break from ActiveRecord, where the actual data is stored elsewhere (i.e. in the database).  In my case I want to load all the data, query it this way and that, and then drop out.

My other approach is to use two classes, one for the individual record and antother for the collection, e.g.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :addresss, :city, :country
end
class PeopleCollection
  def initialize(file)
    @cache = []
    # load file and place each record into @cache as a Person instance
  end
  def all_people
    @cache
  end
  def people_in_city(city)
    # search @cache for matching records
  end
  def people_with_last_name(name)
    # search @cache for matching records
  end
  # etc, etc
end
```

I realize I could just use `CSV::Row` for my record class, or `Hash`, but I want to provide dot notation accessors.  I also looked at `OpenStruct` by it relies on `method_missing` which bugs me in terms of performance impact (but not a deal breaker) and also a I want an exception raised when I hit `record.some_missspelled_attribute_accezzor`

**Update**

A third way occurred, namely to have a single class, with the collection held in a class variable.  Similar to my single-class approach above, but with the collection more explicitly shared.

```
class People
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :addresss, :city, :country
  def self.load(file)
    rtn = self.new
    @@cache = []
    # load data into @@cache instance var, each row of data is an instance of self
    rtn
  end
  def self.all_people
    @@cache
  end
  def self.people_in_city(city)
    # search @@cache for matching records
  end
  def self.people_with_last_name(name)
    # search @@cache for matching records
  end
  # etc, etc
end
```

Comment: the second one seems good, i recently did something similar

Comment: `OpenStruct` is really slow. Use `Struct` when you know the structure: `Person = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :country)`

Answer (score 0):

first, think about the level of abstraction you want to work at. There isn't anything wrong with method_missing. ActiveRecord itself uses method_missing (a lot) - it's just that method_missing is one thing that is heavily leveraged in the Ruby world when you do metaprogramming.

If you need to load CSV files you can go ahead and just use the parser that comes with the stdlib: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

If you are processing other types of files, and CSV was picked as an example, you can also use readlines: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines

One thing to be careful about is loading the whole file into memory vs stream processing. Whenever possible you should aim for stream processing (ie just load the current line that you are processing). The speed difference is negligible for small files and it will work regardless of the file size (if you load everything in memory things will crawl to a halt for large input files).

Personally I would go ahead with the OpenStruct as I see nothing wrong with method missing. If you don't want to do that you can always do the metaprogramming yourself: look at define_method http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method

Comment: Thanks Mircea.  To clarify, I'm all too familiar with CSV, IO, etc.  As I mention, this is not a question about file formats or how to parse them, but rather how to model the data in-memory.  Also, as I mentioned, `method_missing ` is not a deal breaker for me, but the way `OpenStruct` returns nil for a undefined key is undesirable (for me, in this case).  What I'm really asking is, do I need two classes (collection, record) or can I somehow get away with one or is there some other pattern I should be looking at?

Comment: my intuition would be to use a built-in collection and only to model the record. YMMV and you may want to build something that includes Enumerable and lazily load the data when needed.